# Roman Numerals to Integers Converter with Python using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I'm learning to code and I had an exercise to make a converter of roman numerals to integers. I realize there are a lot of different ways to write this program, but I would appreciate it if you could help me find my mistake. I'd love to hear suggestions on how to write it better, but what I really could use right now is understanding what I did wrong with this one.

I have a dictionary called `roman_numerals`. Its `keys` are the roman numeral values, and its `values` are their matching integer.

```
roman_numerals = {"M":1000,"CM":900,"D":500,"CD":400,"C":100,"XC":90,"L":50,"XL":40,"X":10,"V":5,"IV":4,"I":1}

def roman_int(user_choice):
    if user_choice == "1":
        user_roman = input("What numeral would you like to convert?\n").upper()
        resultI = 0
        for k,v in roman_numerals.items():          
            if user_roman == k:
                resultI += roman_numerals.get(user_roman)
            else:
                for i in user_roman:
                    if i in roman_numerals.keys():
                        if i == k:
                            resultI += v
    print(resultI)
```

When I run my code,if I use a numeral that is equal to a `key` of more than one character ("IV" for example) I get a result that is an addition of both "IV" and "V". or "CM" and "M".
I know why it happens, because I asked for an iteration. But, can I ask my program to stop iterating when it returns a value? I feel like I'm really close to the solution, but I'm just confused at this point.

Thank you!

Comment: I beleive my answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that you consume all characters that contribute to the sum. Since all the multi-char "atomic" literals begin with the lower valued unit, and otherwise, higher valued units come first, a simple greedy approach is workable:

- Try to convert the first two chars as a whole, if that's not possible, convert the first single char.
- Move forward the appropriate number of steps.

  ```
  def roman_int(user_roman):
      user_roman = user_roman.upper()
      resultI = 0

      while user_roman:
          # try first two chars
          if user_roman[:2] in roman_numerals:
              resultI += roman_numerals[user_roman[:2]]
              # cut off first two chars
              user_roman = user_roman[2:]
          # try first char
          elif user_roman[:1] in roman_numerals:
              resultI += roman_numerals[user_roman[:1]]
              # cut off first char
              user_roman = user_roman[1:]
          else:
              print('No roman number')
              return
      print(resultI)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to represent the values as a list of tuples, since this allows us to define an *order* in them, and therefore we can avoid matching `'I'` in case the string contains at that point `'IX'`. So we can define the conversion as:

```
roman_numerals = [
    ('M', 1000),
    ('CM', 900),
    ('D', 500),
    ('CD', 400),
    ('C', 100),
    ('XC', 90),
    ('L', 50),
    ('XL', 40),
    ('X', 10),
    ('IX', 9),
    ('V', 5),
    ('IV', 4),
    ('I', 1)
]
```

Note that you forgot to use `IX`, this makes it to some extent problematic, since it will interpret `IX` as `11`.

Now we can process the string by each time performing a [**`str.startswith()`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) check, and from the moment we found a prefix, add the corresponding value, and advance the offset of the string, like:

```
def roman_int(user_choice):
    ix = 0
    result = 0
    while ix < len(user_choice):
        for k, v in roman_numerals:
            if user_choice.startswith(k, ix):
                result += v
                ix += len(k)
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Roman number.')
    return result
```

We thus enumerate through the string, and each time look to match a Roman numeral. For example:

```
>>> roman_int('MCMXC')
1990
>>> roman_int('MCMXCIII')
1993
>>> roman_int('MMXVIII')
2018
```

The system will also error if for example we enter invalid characters:

```
>>> roman_int('MMXQVIII')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in roman_int
ValueError: Invalid Roman number.
```

The above is however not very efficient: each time we enumerate `roman_literals` until we find the match. But once we are processing the "fifties" (`L`), then we know that we will never parse "thousands" (`M`) again. We can boost performance by remembering the index in the `roman_numerals`:

```
def roman_int(user_choice):
    ix = 0
    iy = 0
    result = 0
    while ix < len(user_choice):
        while iy < len(roman_numerals) and not user_choice.startswith(roman_numerals[iy][0], ix):
            iy += 1
        if iy < len(roman_numerals):
            result += roman_numerals[iy][1]
            ix += len(roman_numerals[iy][0])
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Roman numeral')
    return result
```

This again yields the results we expect:

```
>>> roman_int('MDCCLXXVI')
1776
>>> roman_int('MCMLIV')
1954
>>> roman_int('MCMXC')
1990
>>> roman_int('MMXIV')
2014
>>> roman_int('MMXVIII')
2018
```

But is also stricter, for example `CMM` is *not* a valid Roman numeral, whereas `MCM` is:

```
>>> roman_int('CMM')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in roman_int
ValueError: Invalid Roman numeral
>>> roman_int('MCM')
1900
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of occurences of each numeral in string instead of checking string for occurrences, then just remove the occurrences where double letters such as `CM` appear so remove nulber of occurrences of `CM` * value of `C` and `M`

```
roman_numerals = {"M":1000,"CM":900,"D":500,"CD":400,"C":100,"XC":90,"L":50,"XL":40,"X":10,"IX":9, "V":5,"IV":4,"I":1}

def roman_int(user_choice):
    if user_choice == "1":
        result = 0
        user_roman = input("What numeral would you like to convert?\n").upper()
        for k,v in roman_numerals.items():          
            result += v * user_roman.count(k)
            if len(k) == 2:
                result -= roman_numerals[k[0]] * user_roman.count(k)
                result -= roman_numerals[k[1]] * user_roman.count(k)                
    print(result)

roman_int("1")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through the dictionary. My code is slightly different but I have tried to keep as much of your code as possible.

```
roman_numerals =  {"M":1000,"CM":900,"D":500,"CD":400,"C":100,"XC":90,"L":50,"XL":40,"X":10,"V":5,"IV":4,"I":1}

def roman_int(user_choice):
    if user_choice == "1":
        user_roman = input("What numeral would you like to convert?\n").upper()
        result = 0
        values = []

        # return the result if the input is in the dictionary
        try:
            result = roman_numerals[user_roman]
        except KeyError:
            # split up the user input and convert each character into corresponding numeral
            for i in user_roman:
                try:
                    value = roman_numerals[i]
                    values.append(value)
                # if user enters character not used in roman numerals
                except KeyError:
                    print("Not valid input")
            # loop through all values and add them up
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                try:
                    # if a value is larger than the next value, add it
                    if value > values[i+1]:
                        result += value
                    # else the number is obtained by substracting the smaller value from the larger value
                    else:
                        actual_value = values[i+1] - value
                        result = result + actual_value
                        #set the next number to 0 as it has already been added
                        values[i+1] = 0
                except IndexError:
                    # this try except block catches the IndexError exception caused when i+1 > len(values)
                    pass
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it I guess

```
roman_numerals = {"M":1000,"CM":900,"D":500,"CD":400,"C":100,"XC":90,"L":50,"XL":40,"X":10,"V":5,"IV":4,"I":1}

def roman_int(user_choice):
    if user_choice == "1":
        user_roman = input("What numeral would you like to convert?\n").upper()
        resultI = 0
        pos = 0
        try:
            resultI = roman_numerals[user_roman]
        except:
            try:
                while pos < len(user_roman):
                    resultI += roman_numerals[user_roman[pos]]
                    pos+=1
            except:
                print('Not present in our dictionary')
    print(resultI)
```